# How to grab the stack of a GPFed application?

Tags: windows-xp, crash, stack

I have an app with many components that crashes with a GPF.  The ModName is listed as one of the main modules within the application.  It calls a bunch of other modules depending on the situation.

Using tools like Process Explorer and others, is it possible to identify the stack that led to the crash?

Edit: I should add that this is a native code C++ application.